# Список клиентов. В чем ошибка?

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте!) Посмотрите что не так?

Активируется socket и отправляется сообщение:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if organiz.Text <> '' then
begin
ClientSocket1.Address:='127.0.0.1';
ClientSocket1.Port:=3030;
clientsocket1.Active:=true;
ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(organiz.Text);
end
else
begin
organiz.SetFocus;
MessageDlg('Введите название организации', mtError,[mbOK],0);
end;
end;
```

Здесь запоминается и выводится socket:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  j:=j+1;
  sockets[j]:=Socket.SocketHandle;
  n:=j;
  chat.Lines.Insert(0,inttostr(sockets[j]));
end;
```

Здесь должно приниматься сообщение с именем клиента и выводиться в clients (ListBox):

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  var s: string;
begin
for i:=1 to n do
 if Socket.SocketHandle = sockets[i] then
 begin
  s:=socket.ReceiveText;
  name[i]:=s;
  clients.items.add(s);
 end;
end;
```

но почему то ничего не выводится...
 Смысл всего этого в том, чтоб при подключение клиента, в массив (sockets) заносилось значение socket.handle. Далее сразу же посылалось сообщение, содержащие имя клиента, которое также запоминалось в массиве (name) и заносилось в clients (listBox), чтоб потом прежде чем отправить сообщение, надо выбрать из списка имя клиента и потом по значению sockets этого имени отправлять сообщение, т.е определенному клиенту... А дальше при посылке другого сообщение проверять есть ли такой socket.handle в массиве, если да то проводить другой анализ, если нет, то записываем... но что то не так пошло с самого начало, а вот что? Спасибо)

Comment: Сорри за дурацкий вопрос: sockets[j] = ...  - у вас там гигантский массив заранее заготовлен, чтобы сокеты запоминать?

Comment: И ещё: что значит не выводится? Что дебаг показывает? ServerSocket1ClientConnect вызывается? А ServerSocket1ClientRead?

Comment: И что за дурдом у вас в ServerSocket1ClientRead? Это у вас такое делается из-за отсутствия "каркаса" приложения. У вас получилось желе, а не приложение :)

Comment: Да, в sockets[j] будут храниться сокеты... Не выводится знач - в listBox не заносится socket.ReceiveText, в котором должно передаться значение organiz.text из другой проги - клиента... в  ServerSocket1ClientRead проверяется наличие socket.handle в sockets[j], если есть то в listBox добавляется имя переданное в socket.ReceiveText... но не добавляется... Объясните уж несчастному что и как? как быть, кто виноват и что делать?)

Comment: Для начала надо запуститься в отладчике и поставить точки в этих методах, чтобы понять, а вызываются ли они вообще. Заоднно вы сможете увидеть, если выполнение пойдёт не по плану :) По поводу передачи разнородных данных: вам нужен какой-то нормальный протокол передачи данных. Например, вы можете использовать XML.

Comment: Ну как бы номер сокета он передает, т.е подключается клиент, это я пробовал, а вот сообщение нет почему то... А про XML где можно почитать?...

Comment: я конечно не знаю, копипаст это или ручками печаталось..
но clientsocket1.Active:=true; - с маленькой буквы :)

по поводу xml: http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/xml/

Comment: Паскаль - case insensitive. Ему всё равно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть идея. Прочтите здесь: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ScktComp.TClientSocket.Active. Тут сказано, что в рантайме надо использовать Open.

> At **design** time, set Active to true to make the socket open a connection when the application starts running. **At runtime**, use the Open or Close method to open or close the connection.

Лично у меня есть подозрение, что установка Active=true асинхронна, так что в тот момент, когда вы пытаетесь что-то отправить (вызываете SendText) сокет ещё не подключён.

Для того, чтобы быть уверенным, что вы шлёте данные, когда действительно имеете такую возможность, делайте это тогда и только тогда, когда соединение установлено. Например, слушайте событие [OnConnect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ScktComp.TClientSocket.OnConnect) компонента ClientSocket. И не забывайте обрабатывать ошибки. В сети вероятность коммуникационных ошибок очень велика, поэтмоу не следует ею пренебрегать.

И последнее: вы используете метод [SendText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ScktComp.TCustomWinSocket.SendText). Этот метод посылает текст.. в какой-то кодировке.. один бог ведает, в какой. Это очень непереносимо и моджет вызвать неприятности с кодировками и, как следствие, получение мусора. Так же, этот метод возвращает количество байт, которые были переданы и это количество может быть меньше, чем вы просили передать. Это означает, что надо по идее проверять, а было ли послано всё или только часть. И уж совсем плохо (серьёзный недостаток API, упущение борланда) то, что он возвращает количество байт, а на вход принимает символы. Это не всегда одно и то же и не всегда можно узнать, какое количество символов соответствует этим байтам, так как это зависит от кодировки. Правда, пока у вас винда одной версии на обеих сторонах, бояться нечего. Но времена меняются. Надо сразу привыкать думать о таких вещах.

Всё-таки надо сделать ещё дополнение, касающееся сервера: у вас наблюдается серьёзная ошибка: при чтении из сокета вы добавляете элемент в список.. а теперь представьте, что наименование длинное, а фрагментация в сети высокая.. тогда наименование теоретически может начать приходить порциями.. т.е. вызов ServerSocket1ClientRead будет выполняться более одного раза для одного клиента и вы можете добавить несколько элементов в выпадающий список для одного клиента.. начало, продолжение.. потом конец.

По поводу XML:

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

После освоения можно браться за реализацию

http://www.codenet.ru/cat/Languages/Delphi/Delphi-XML/

Ну и конечно же, источник истины в первой инстранции по XML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/

Comment: Пробовал я, изменял Active на True, и толку нет, может быть сообщение должно посылаться через некоторое время? а не сразу после подключения?..

Comment: При чём тут True? В документации написано, что вы вообще не должны использовать Active.

Comment: Что значит сразу после подключения? Тот факт что вы установили Active=true ещё не означает, что подключение будет установлено немедленно и что на следующей строчке вы уже сможете с ним работать. Active вообще сделать только для дизайнера форм и поэтому вообще не документирован толком.

Comment: Извините опечатался, по привычке после Active true, конечно же Open, пробовал)И как бы подключение осуществляется, потому что chat.Lines.Insert(0,inttostr(sockets[j])) выводится какой сокет подключен...

Comment: Попробуйте с событием OnConnect

Comment: Нет же. Соединение устанавливается, но я подозреваю, что вы вызываете SendText слишком рано. Вы как будто не читаете вообще.. Если вы посылаете в идеальных условиях в сокет данные, а они не передаются, то это значит, что вы либо шлёте в ещё не открытый (закрытый) сокет, либо проблема связана с какой-нибудь буфферизацией. Проверьте вы в конце концов, что функция SendText возвращает.

Comment: Я проверил таким методом, если он правильный конечно, k:=ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(organiz.text); 
chat.Lines.Insert(0,inttostr(k)); и получил "0"..((

Comment: Используйте Open, создайте обработчик OnConnect для ClientSocket1. Внутри него напишите ClientSocket1.Socket.SendText(organiz.Text); а из обрботчика кнопки уберите. В метод ServerSocket1ClientRead добавьте какой-нибудь дебаг (например, MEssageDlg('AAA', mtError', [mbOk], 0)) или поставте там точку останова, чтобы проверить, вызывается этот метод вообще или нет.

Comment: Вот именно, что 0. Это означает, что сокет думает, что не готов посылать. Рано ещё что-то посылать, как я и пытаюсь вам объяснить.